# How to get the name of program running on windows with c#

Tags: c#, process

I want a function that give me a name of program(like msPaint or notepad) that when i work with notepad, this function return "Notepad" , when i work with msPaint, this function return "msPaint".

Please help me...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12372534/how-to-get-a-process-window-class-name-from-c

Answer (score 3):

Using `Process.GetProcesses();` method you can get all running application and if you want current active window then make use of `GetForegroundWindow()` and `GetWindowText()`.

for example [click here](http://www.csharphelp.com/2006/08/get-current-window-handle-and-caption-with-windows-api-in-c/)

Comment: how to change 'GetForegroundWindow()' to name of this program?

Comment: this is might be helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6569405/how-to-get-active-process-name-in-c

Answer (score 2):

You can use the Process class. It has a Modules property that lists all the loaded modules.

To list all processes and all modules to the console:

```
Process[] processes = Process.GetProcesses();

    foreach(Process process in processes) {
    Console.WriteLine("PID:  " + process.Id);
    Console.WriteLine("Name: " + process.Name);
    Console.WriteLine("Modules:");
    foreach(ProcessModule module in process.Modules) {
        Console.WriteLine(module.FileName);
    }
```

Or do like this,

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
private static extern IntPtr GetForegroundWindow();

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
private static extern int GetWindowText(IntPtr hWnd, StringBuilder text, int count);

public static void Main()
{
    int chars = 256;
    StringBuilder buff = new StringBuilder(chars);
    while (true)
    {
        // Obtain the handle of the active window.
        IntPtr handle = GetForegroundWindow();

        // Update the controls.
        if (GetWindowModuleFileName(handle, buff, chars) > 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(buff.ToString());
            Console.WriteLine(handle.ToString());
        }
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

From: [How to get a process window class name from c#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12372534/how-to-get-a-process-window-class-name-from-c)

```
    int pidToSearch = 316;
    //Init a condition indicating that you want to search by process id.
    var condition = new PropertyCondition(AutomationElementIdentifiers.ProcessIdProperty, 
        pidToSearch);
    //Find the automation element matching the criteria
    AutomationElement element = AutomationElement.RootElement.FindFirst(
        TreeScope.Children, condition);

    //get the classname
    var className = element.Current.ClassName;
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how you are calling these programs. If you running these programs through Process, you can get through ProcessName.

Example:

```
        Process tp = Process.Start(@"notepad.exe", "temp");

        string s = tp.ProcessName;
```